# Como concatenar variável com objeto vazio (entre chaves)?

Tags: javascript

Para adicionar valor em arrays (entre colchetes []) uso `$objeto.push('novoValor');`

Como faço para adicionar valores em variáveis entre chaves (objeto vazio)?

Exemplo :

`$objeto = {}`  adicionar  `$objeto = {"conteudo":"dado"}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$objeto = {}; 
$objeto.conteudo = [];

for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  $objeto.conteudo.push({"dado":"" + i});
}
console.log($objeto.conteudo);
```

```js
$objeto = {};
$objeto.conteudo = "dado";
alert($objeto.conteudo);
```

JavaScript é uma linguagem dinâmica, ou seja, você pode definir novas propriedades para um objeto em qualquer ponto da execução.

Portanto, para adicionar o valor a que se refere, basta atribuir diretamente para a propriedade:

```
$objeto.conteudo = "dado";
```

Comment: Sei que já respondeu e agradeço bastante. Mas é que é que eu queria concatenar recursivamente. Ir inserindo os valores formando um JSON.

Fiz a seguinte versão do código:

$objeto = {};
  $objeto.conteudo = $objeto.conteudo+'{"dado":"1"}';
  $objeto.conteudo = $objeto.conteudo+'{"dado":"2"}';
  $objeto.conteudo = $objeto.conteudo+'{"dado":"3"}';  
  console.log($objeto.conteudo);

O resultado foi:

undefined{"dado":"1"}{"dado":"2"}{"dado":"3"}

Comment: Editei a minha resposta com o exemplo citado. É isso que estava pensando? No meu entendimento, você quer um array "conteudo" dentro do seu objeto.

Comment: Caso seja isso mesmo, te sugiro editar a pergunta para que fique mais claro para quem for consultar depois. Também edito a minha resposta para ficar alinhado.

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Deixei a pergunta mais clara. Mais uma vez obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Se já tens uma variável com um objeto vazio podes fazer simplesmente

```
obj.propriedade = valor;
```

Se estiveres a iniciar tudo podes fazer:

```
var obj = {propriedade: valor};
```

Se a(s)  propriedade(s) forem dinâmicas, ou seja o nome da própria propriedade/chave estiver dentro de uma variável, então podes fazer assim:

```
var prop = 'minhaPropriedade';
var obj = {[prop]: 12345};
console.log(obj.minhaPropriedade); // dá 12345
```